# How to enable CodeFirst to migrate schema changes against a replicated database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations

Running any migration that alters existing replicated tables fails with the following error:

**You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or REPEATABLE READ isolation levels.**

Have tried taking the scripts generated during the migration and executing in sql under same user and they work.

Is there a setting somewhere that may allow these updates to go through?

Comment: what's your question ?

Comment: I'm not certain what you are asking but to me this looks to be more about Database Administration thing rather than a programming problem, you might get more (and better) help on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess the question is has anyone else hit this issue? And the only reason I put it here is because the error is displayed within the visual studio package manager console.

Comment: Database triggers resolved the issue
http://grumpydba.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-2008-adding-column-to-replicated.html

Comment: As an alternative, you can force a different isolation level during migration. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127647/how-to-set-the-isolation-level-for-entity-framework-codefirst-migrations .