# How to set the isolation level for Entity Framework CodeFirst Migrations

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

If you run an entity framework migration (either automatic or explicit) against tables published for SQL Server replication you get the following error:

> You can only specify the READPAST lock in the READ COMMITTED or
>   REPEATABLE READ isolation levels

There have been questions about this before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789395/how-to-enable-codefirst-to-migrate-schema-changes-against-a-replicated-database)), but they completely fail to address the underlying cause: *Entity Framework migration is run at the `Serializable` isolation level* (as clearly shown in the SQL Server profiler).

Which is a safe choice for a structure-changing transaction, but it simply isn't compatible with published sql server tables. Unlike the default READ COMMITED SNAPSHOT level used in the `dbContext.SaveChanges()` transactions, I haven't yet found a way to actually set a different isolation level for migrations in the code:

- `TransactionScope` (the classic way to set isolation level for transactions) seems to be ignored during `Database.Initialize()`
- The recently introduced `Database.BeginTransaction(isolationLevel)` actually attempts to initialize the database before starting the new transaction, so can't be used.

**Known Workarounds**

1. Generate all migrations to SQL script. This works, but code-based migrations are a powerful instrument I wouldn't like to miss out on.
2. Use explicit migrations, and start each `Up()` and `Down()` method with something like

   Sql("set transaction isolation level read committed");

This works, but is inconvenient and error-prone as developers typically don't work with a replicated database..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Would it help to create your onw Migrator?

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<SupplierEntities>
{
  public Configuration()
  {
    SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new SqlMigrator());
  }

  private class SqlMigrator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
  {
    public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(
      IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
    {
      yield return new MigrationStatement { Sql = "set transaction isolation level read committed" };
      foreach (var statement in base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken))
        yield return statement;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. What a fantastic answer, this really helps with a code-first designed replicated database, where the issue isn't very documented.

I don't have a hat, but if I did it would be tipped in your direction

Answer (score 2):

You can write and execute SQL in your migration code:

Before SQL Server 2012 use dynamic SQL:

```
public override void Up()
{
     Sql("DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) = 'ALTER DATABASE '+ DB_NAME() +' SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON' ; EXEC sp_executeSql @SQL;", true);
}
```

For SQL Server 2012 or later:

```
public override void Up()
{
     Sql("ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON",true);
}
```

Change "ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION" to your isolation level.