# How can I target a EF6 migration to only execute on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, sql-server-ce-4

I would like to ensure specific features are turned on in SQL Server. I am currently using EF6 Migrations to generate my change scripts. I am using my migrations against both SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server CE 4 (for basic unit testing of my mapping). The specific feature I want to enable is not supported by SQL Server CE.

How can I create a migration that only applies to SQL Server?

Here is the migration in question:

```
public partial class EnableSnapshotIsolation : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    { 

        Sql(@"  ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON", true);

        Sql(@"  ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON", true);
    }


    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql(@"  ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT OFF", true);

        Sql(@"  ALTER DATABASE CURRENT
                SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF", true);
    }
}
```

**Note:** that we do manual deployments of change scripts. A person opens a SSMS window and executes the script. I provide a change script using the update-database -script command as part of my build packaging process. So EF is NOT creating the database.

Answer (score 1):

After poking around quite a bit, I found that there is no way in the migration its self to suppress a migration based on database type. But, you can implement your own [migrator for a specific provider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23214959/303).

My solution involves updating my configuration class like so.

```
public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        MigrationsDirectory = "Data\\Migrations";
        SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new SqlMigrator());
    }

    private class SqlMigrator : SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator
    {
        public override IEnumerable<MigrationStatement> Generate(
            IEnumerable<MigrationOperation> migrationOperations, string providerManifestToken)
        {
            var statements = new List<MigrationStatement>
            {
                new MigrationStatement
                {
                    Sql = "ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON",
                    SuppressTransaction = true
                },
                new MigrationStatement
                {
                    Sql = "ALTER DATABASE CURRENT SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON",
                    SuppressTransaction = true
                }
            };
            statements.AddRange(base.Generate(migrationOperations, providerManifestToken));
            return statements;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This of course will fail on Sql Server versions prior to 2012, so make your script as beefy as it needs to be to set these flags. This works for my specific case.